# How do Wikipedia maps add a coordinate point to a base map?

Tags: web-mapping, labeling, point, coordinates

On wikipedia pages for localities, there is often a map on the right side of the page in the introduction, and the map is tagged with the point of the locality. For example, see below:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buenos_Aires]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buenos_Aires

How do I achieve something similar in a website (use one map image, and use code to plot a coordinate point and labelling on the map)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is done using the [WikiProject Geographical coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Geographical_coordinates):

> **WikiProject Geographical coordinates** aims to better organize location
>   information in articles containing a set of numbers that identifies
>   location on and relative to the Earth.